# Updating schema for a IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank Config

Tags: solr, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

Are there ways to update the schema of the Solr config in IBM Watson's Retrieve and Rank service other than deleting, then uploading the config again.

I used the following example to create a new cluster, config and collection.
https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml

I started from the [blank example config](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/configure.shtml) and updated the schema.

I now need to update the schema and add/modify some schema elements. Is there a way to do it without deleting and uploading the config again? How can this be done so that there is minimum downtime when making the change?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but you have to configure Solr to use managed schemas: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Schema+Definition+in+SolrConfig and then the schema APIs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API.

Do note, however, the big caveat on the schema API page:

Re-index after schema modifications!
If you modify your schema, you will likely need to re-index all documents. If you do not, you may lose access to documents, or not be able to interpret them properly, e.g. after replacing a field type.
Modifying your schema will never modify any documents that are already indexed. Again, you must re-index documents in order to apply schema changes to them.

So it will depend on what specific schema changes you need as to whether or not you need to re-index.. If you're adding a new field, no problems... if you're modifying an existing field, this will only impact data you have not indexed yet and it might mean you should re-index (depending on your changes), etc.